# How to use HTTPS with Kestrel server for the .Net Core web api

Tags: .net-core, windows-services

I have created .net core web api. Now its running as the windows background service and its basically listen to the Http request. But I want to change this application to support HTTPS request. So what I did I have changed `Program.cs` file.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);  
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);         
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 443, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.UseHttps("certificate.pfx", "password");
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            }).UseWindowsService();
            });
}
```

But here `.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>` I am getting following error.

```
Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void' [MHScaleInboundWebAPI]csharp(CS0023)
```

So I need to fix this error and need to correct above class to support with the https request like this. `https://localhost:8080/Customer`. I need to change this `Program.cs` calss. I am using  8080 port number.